# Close Notification on Selection of GCM Notification Android

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want to close the notification when the user selects the notification.This is my code that i am using to show the notification to the user.I am using this in **GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)**

```
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);
       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle(" Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg.toString());

        mBuilder.build().flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(notificationSound);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

But this is not working fine for me when i am selecting the notification it is opening the activity but it is not closing the notifications .Please suggest me what went wrong in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID); // use this to cancel notification
```

Or you can try

`mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);`  //so the notification is automatically canceled when the user    clicks it in the panel

Answer (score 1):

Just remove these lines :

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);
```

And

```
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Comment: @Gaurav have you achieved what you want through this, if yes then make it accepted

Answer (score 1):

Use `setAutoCancel (boolean autoCancel)`

`Setting this flag will make it so the notification is automatically canceled when the user clicks it in the panel. The PendingIntent set with setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent) will be broadcast when the notification is canceled.`

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

```
            Notification notification = new Notification(
                    YOUR_DRAWABLE_RESOURCE, "Message",
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

You can use the `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` to cancel notfication when selected.